# R: Read in .csv file and convert into multiple column data frame

Tags: r, csv

I am new to `R` and currently having a plenty of trouble just reading in `.csv` file and converting it into `data.frame` with `7` columns. Here is what I am doing:

```
gene_symbols_table <- as.data.frame(read.csv(file="/home/nikita/Desktop
/CElegans_raw_data/gene_symbols_matching.csv", header=TRUE, sep=","))
```

After that I am getting a `data.frame` with `dim = 46761 x 1`, but I need it to be `46761 x 7`. I tried the following `stackoverflow` threads:

1. [How can you read a CSV file in R with different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922493/how-can-you-read-a-csv-file-in-r-with-different-number-of-columns)
2. [read.delim() - errors "more columns than column names" and "header and ''col.names" are of different lengths"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284146/read-delim-errors-more-columns-than-column-names-and-header-and-col-nam)
3. [Split a column of a data frame to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns)

But somehow nothing is working in my case.
Here is how the table looks:

```
> head(gene_symbols_table, 3)
input.reason.matches.organism.name.primaryIdentifier.symbol.briefDescription.c
lass.secondaryIdentifier
1                     WBGene00008675 MATCH 1 Caenorhabditis elegans    
WBGene00008675 irld-26  Gene F11A5.7
2                      WBGene00008676 MATCH 1 Caenorhabditis elegans 
WBGene00008676 oac-15  Gene F11A5.8
3                            WBGene00008677 MATCH 1 Caenorhabditis elegans 
WBGene00008677   Gene F11A5.9
```

The `.csv` file in `Excel` looks like this:

```
input   |  reason   |  matches  |   organism.name  |    primaryIdentifier   |  symbol   | 
briefDescription
WBGene00008675  |   MATCH  |    1     |   Caenorhabditis elegans    WBGene00008675  |   irld-26   |   ...   
...
```

The following code:

```
gene_symbols_table <- read.table(file="/home/nikita/Desktop
/CElegans_raw_data/gene_symbols_matching.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",", 
col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(7)), fill = TRUE)
```

Seems to be working, however when I look into `dim` I can see right away that it is wrong: `20124 x 7`. Then:

```
V1
1input;reason;matches;organism.name;primaryIdentifier;symbol;briefDescription;class;secondaryIdentifier
2                     WBGene00008675;MATCH;1;Caenorhabditis 
elegans;WBGene00008675;irld-26;;Gene;F11A5.7
3                      WBGene00008676;MATCH;1;Caenorhabditis 
elegans;WBGene00008676;oac-15;;Gene;F11A5.8
  V2 V3 V4 V5
1            
2            
3
```

1

So, it is wrong

Other attempts at `read.table` are giving me the error specified in the second `stackoverflow` thread.

I have also tried splitting the `data.frame` with one column into 7, but so far no success.

Comment: What happens when you change `sep=','` to `sep=';'`?

Comment: `more columns than column names` error

Comment: I think you'll need to include more lines of the file (as displayed in a text editor, not Excel) in order to get help. Your Excel snippet suggests you might need a `sep = "|"` argument but this remains unclear. Also, the response from `read.csv()` is a data frame, so you don't need `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: I added '|' myself here for the sake of visualizing it better. In Excel these are just cells

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Do you have any way of knowing if your data is 'ragged', meaning that some rows could have more or less than 7 columns?  Another reason you could have that error is if you have an index column in your data without a column name.

Comment: The data is fine for sure. I just noticed that when I open the file with LibreOffice I see `Separated by: semicolon, space`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sep` seems to be space or semi-colon, and not comma from what the table looks like. So either try specifying that, or you could try `fread` from the `data.table` package, which automatically detects the separator.

```
gene_symbols_table <- as.data.frame(fread(file="/home/nikita/Desktop
/CElegans_raw_data/gene_symbols_matching.csv", header=TRUE))
```